# Can't parse YAML correctly when number contains leading zeros and for yes/no values

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I parse the following YAML data in Python:

```py
import yaml
yaml.load("""
---
categories: {1: Yes, 2: No}
increasing: [00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10]
""")
```

And get this as output:

```py
{'increasing': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, '08', '09', 10], 'categories': {1: True, 2: False}}
```

- Why are `Yes` and `No` converted to `True` and `False`?
- Why are `08` and `09` parsed as strings whereas the other digits are parsed as numbers with leading zeros truncated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your deduction that for `00` to `07` the leading zeros are truncated is incorrect. These are all octal characters because of the leading `0` and interpreted as such.

As octal characters cannot contain `8` or `9` the `08` and `09` cannot be anything but strings, and your YAML parser loads them as such.

This is actually a leftover (backwards compatibility) with [YAML 1.1](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2507367) in [YAML 1.2 octal numbers](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764652) should start with `0o`

That `Yes` and `No` are loaded as `True` and `False` resp. is also a YAML-1.1-ishm. The 1.2 specification no longer refers to these alternatives. If you quote those strings, they will not be converted

You can relatively easily build a resolver that doesn't accept the Yes/No/On/Off variants for True/False by adding the following rule:

```
MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:bool',
    re.compile(u'''^(?:true|True|TRUE|false|False|FALSE)$''', re.X),
    list(u'tTfF'))
```

or by using the normal `Resolver` and deleting the appropriate start symbol entries:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
from ruamel.yaml.resolver import Resolver

yaml_str = """\
categories: {1: Yes, 2: No}
"""

for ch in list(u'yYnNoO'):
    del Resolver.yaml_implicit_resolvers[ch]


data = yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=yaml.Loader)
print(data)
```

gives you:

```
{'categories': {1: 'Yes', 2: 'No'}}
```

Making all number-only strings that start with 0 to be recognised as normal integers is not so simple, because if you change the implicit resolver for `int` and pass the strings on that start with 0, you get a parsing problem, because `08` is converted based on octal ¹:

```
import re
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
from ruamel.yaml.reader import Reader
from ruamel.yaml.resolver import BaseResolver, Resolver
from ruamel.yaml.scanner import RoundTripScanner
from ruamel.yaml.parser_ import Parser
from ruamel.yaml.composer import Composer
from ruamel.yaml.constructor import RoundTripConstructor
from ruamel.yaml import RoundTripLoader
from ruamel.yaml.compat import to_str


yaml_str = """\
categories: {1: Yes, 2: No}
increasing: [00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10]
"""


class MyResolver(BaseResolver):
    pass

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:bool',
    re.compile(u'''^(?:true|True|TRUE|false|False|FALSE)$''', re.X),
    list(u'tTfF'))

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:float',
    re.compile(u'''^(?:
     [-+]?(?:[0-9][0-9_]*)\\.[0-9_]*(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
    |[-+]?(?:[0-9][0-9_]*)(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)
    |\\.[0-9_]+(?:[eE][-+][0-9]+)?
    |[-+]?[0-9][0-9_]*(?::[0-5]?[0-9])+\\.[0-9_]*
    |[-+]?\\.(?:inf|Inf|INF)
    |\\.(?:nan|NaN|NAN))$''', re.X),
    list(u'-+0123456789.'))

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int',
    re.compile(u'''^(?:[-+]?0b[0-1_]+
    |[-+]?[0-9]+
    |[-+]?0o?[0-7_]+
    |[-+]?(?:0|[1-9][0-9_]*)
    |[-+]?0x[0-9a-fA-F_]+
    |[-+]?[1-9][0-9_]*(?::[0-5]?[0-9])+)$''', re.X),
    list(u'-+0123456789'))

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:merge',
    re.compile(u'^(?:<<)$'),
    [u'<'])

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null',
    re.compile(u'''^(?: ~
    |null|Null|NULL
    | )$''', re.X),
    [u'~', u'n', u'N', u''])

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:timestamp',
    re.compile(u'''^(?:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]
    |[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] -[0-9][0-9]? -[0-9][0-9]?
    (?:[Tt]|[ \\t]+)[0-9][0-9]?
    :[0-9][0-9] :[0-9][0-9] (?:\\.[0-9]*)?
    (?:[ \\t]*(?:Z|[-+][0-9][0-9]?(?::[0-9][0-9])?))?)$''', re.X),
    list(u'0123456789'))

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:value',
    re.compile(u'^(?:=)$'),
    [u'='])

# The following resolver is only for documentation purposes. It cannot work
# because plain scalars cannot start with '!', '&', or '*'.
MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:yaml',
    re.compile(u'^(?:!|&|\\*)$'),
    list(u'!&*'))


class MyRoundTripConstructor(RoundTripConstructor):
    def construct_yaml_int(self, node):
        value = to_str(self.construct_scalar(node))
        value = value.replace('_', '')
        sign = +1
        if value[0] == '-':
            sign = -1
        if value[0] in '+-':
            value = value[1:]
        if value == '0':
            return 0
        elif value.startswith('0b'):
            return sign*int(value[2:], 2)
        elif value.startswith('0x'):
            return sign*int(value[2:], 16)
        elif value.startswith('0o'):
            return sign*int(value[2:], 8)
        #elif value[0] == '0':
        #    return sign*int(value, 8)
        elif ':' in value:
            digits = [int(part) for part in value.split(':')]
            digits.reverse()
            base = 1
            value = 0
            for digit in digits:
                value += digit*base
                base *= 60
            return sign*value
        else:
            return sign*int(value)

MyRoundTripConstructor.add_constructor(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int',
    MyRoundTripConstructor.construct_yaml_int)


class MyRoundTripLoader(Reader, RoundTripScanner, Parser,
                      Composer, MyRoundTripConstructor, MyResolver):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        Reader.__init__(self, stream)
        RoundTripScanner.__init__(self)
        Parser.__init__(self)
        Composer.__init__(self)
        MyRoundTripConstructor.__init__(self)
        MyResolver.__init__(self)

for ch in list(u'yYnNoO'):
    del Resolver.yaml_implicit_resolvers[ch]

data = yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=MyRoundTripLoader)
print(data['increasing'])
```

and that prints:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

(it also does Yes/No as strings, without first inserting the recognition patterns in the internal lookup table)

---

¹ <sub>I used [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) for this, of which I am the author. [PyYAML](https://bitbucket.org/xi/pyyaml), on which ruamel.yaml is based, should be able to support a similar derivation.</sub>

Comment: To adapt ruamel.yaml to only accept 1.1-ishms like Yes/No, if you specify backwards compatibility, is on the ToDo list.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and comprehensive clarification. Sadly YAML 1.2 currently does not seem to be well supported. Most implementations I've seen are based on 1.1 including the only `R` option `yaml` which is based on `libyaml` 1.1.

Comment: @JonasSchöley Yes libyaml (and PyYAML) are pre 1.2 and not updated. The also hiccup on some JSON compatibilities. The step from 1.1. to 1.2 is not well documented with examples on what used to work and doesn't anymore (and vv.) that makes it hard for parser implementers to stay compatible or even check if updating the parser is necessary. As  PyYAML (and currently ruamel.yaml as well) has the resolver patterns as globals set at module load time, it is non-trivial to make a 1.1/1.2 distinction.

Comment: @Anthon In my case I'd like to use the long example code you posted here, but I still want yes/no to be read in as booleans (but not on/off).

`MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:bool',
 re.compile(u'''^(?:true|True|TRUE|false|False|FALSE|yes|Yes|YES|no|No|NO)$''', re.X),
    list(u'tTfFyYnN'))`

then that works. Is that the right way to do it or am I missing anything?

Comment: @BrianM. That looks ok to me. The original code is similar (look at the first call to `add_implicit_resolver` in `resolver.py` in the YAML source code

Answer (score 0):

`Yes` and `No` have special meanings in YAML. Have a look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Casting_data_types). To circumvent this you could change your YAML to include quotes and look like this

```
>>> yaml.load("""
... ---
... categories: {1: "Yes", 2: "No"}
... increasing: [00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10]
... ...
... """)
```

Regarding the leading zeroes of 08 and 09 i am not quite sure why this is happening, but it does'nt seem to be a python issue

Comment: Python interpretes numbers with a leading zero as octal numbers. An decimal `8` ist `010` in octal. A number with the digit `8` or `9` after a leading `0` makes no sense in octal notatation. Therefor it is parsed as a string.

Comment: Thanks for clarification

Comment: @SebastianStigler That is only partly true, and is **not** the reason why the YAML parser interprets these numbers as octal. The PyYAML and ruamel.yaml parsers **explicitly** check for a leading zero and then call `int(value, 8)`. And only python2 interprets `017` as octal (15 decimal), starting with python 3 `017` throws a SyntaxError.