# yes or no dumping as 'yes' or 'no' in PyYAML

Tags: python-2.7, pyyaml

While dumping a dictionary containing values YES, NO to YAML using PyYAML, The YES/NO  is quoted like 'YES' or 'NO'. How can I get YES or NO with out quotes?

Comment: Have you tried not using strings?

Comment: for example ,                                                                                                 import yaml 
d= {'sample': 'yes'}
print yaml.dump(d)
        The result is      {sample: 'yes'}   . The values yes/no true/false are over quoting while dump . but I need the result as {samle: yes}

Comment: If you need the value for `samle`/`sample` to load back as a boolean (which is what you get when you load `{sample: yes}`, why don't you write out a boolean in the first place. Or do you need to write out YAML 1.2 conform output (and not YAML 1.1. which is what PyYAML gives you). It would be helpful if you explained **why** you need to write out the string "Yes" as a boolean value.

Comment: in my yaml file I don't need boolean types . I need to dump boolean as yes or no but with out quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dump `YES`/`yes`/`Yes` and `NO`/`no`/`No` as non-quoted scalars, you have to make a resolver (that code is used by the PyYAML dumper and the PyYAML loader), in a similar way as [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32966525/1307905) prevents loading these values from YAML as booleans.

```
import re
import yaml as yaml
from yaml.resolver import BaseResolver, Resolver
from yaml.emitter import Emitter
from yaml.serializer import Serializer
from yaml.representer import Representer as Repr


class MyResolver(BaseResolver):
    pass

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:bool',
    re.compile(u'''^(?:true|True|TRUE|false|False|FALSE)$''', re.X),
    list(u'tTfF'))

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:float',
    re.compile(u'''^(?:
     [-+]?(?:[0-9][0-9_]*)\\.[0-9_]*(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
    |[-+]?(?:[0-9][0-9_]*)(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)
    |\\.[0-9_]+(?:[eE][-+][0-9]+)?
    |[-+]?[0-9][0-9_]*(?::[0-5]?[0-9])+\\.[0-9_]*
    |[-+]?\\.(?:inf|Inf|INF)
    |\\.(?:nan|NaN|NAN))$''', re.X),
    list(u'-+0123456789.'))

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int',
    re.compile(u'''^(?:[-+]?0b[0-1_]+
    |[-+]?[0-9]+
    |[-+]?0o?[0-7_]+
    |[-+]?(?:0|[1-9][0-9_]*)
    |[-+]?0x[0-9a-fA-F_]+
    |[-+]?[1-9][0-9_]*(?::[0-5]?[0-9])+)$''', re.X),
    list(u'-+0123456789'))

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:merge',
    re.compile(u'^(?:<<)$'),
    [u'<'])

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null',
    re.compile(u'''^(?: ~
    |null|Null|NULL
    | )$''', re.X),
    [u'~', u'n', u'N', u''])

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:timestamp',
    re.compile(u'''^(?:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]
    |[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] -[0-9][0-9]? -[0-9][0-9]?
    (?:[Tt]|[ \\t]+)[0-9][0-9]?
    :[0-9][0-9] :[0-9][0-9] (?:\\.[0-9]*)?
    (?:[ \\t]*(?:Z|[-+][0-9][0-9]?(?::[0-9][0-9])?))?)$''', re.X),
    list(u'0123456789'))

MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:value',
    re.compile(u'^(?:=)$'),
    [u'='])

# The following resolver is only for documentation purposes. It cannot work
# because plain scalars cannot start with '!', '&', or '*'.
MyResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:yaml',
    re.compile(u'^(?:!|&|\\*)$'),
    list(u'!&*'))


class MySafeDumper(Emitter, Serializer, Repr, MyResolver):
    def __init__(self, stream,
                 default_style=None, default_flow_style=None,
                 canonical=None, indent=None, width=None,
                 allow_unicode=None, line_break=None,
                 encoding=None, explicit_start=None, explicit_end=None,
                 version=None, tags=None):
        Emitter.__init__(self, stream, canonical=canonical,
                         indent=indent, width=width,
                         allow_unicode=allow_unicode, line_break=line_break)
        Serializer.__init__(self, encoding=encoding,
                            explicit_start=explicit_start,
                            explicit_end=explicit_end,
                            version=version, tags=tags)
        Repr.__init__(self, default_style=default_style,
                                 default_flow_style=default_flow_style)
        MyResolver.__init__(self)

print(yaml.dump(dict(sampe='Yes'), Dumper=MySafeDumper))
```

this gives:

```
{sampe: Yes}
```

as you indicated in your comment. If you want to be able to load that as strings as well, you should use the constructor code from the answer linked to above, the resolver parts are the same for both answers.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. I have added constructors  and resolver which are working fine .